# How to apply condition before where clause within CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a problem regarding a select query, I'm using CTE for execute a query, my query is how to apply condition in CTE before `Where` clause,

Table `Temp`:

```
    Id | Title
  --------------    
    1  |  ABCD
    2  |  ABCD
    3  |  AB
    4  |  CD
    5  |  DA

Declare @Count int,@search nvarchar(50)

Select @search ='AB'

set @Count =1

WITH TempResult as          
    (              
        Select * from Temp
    )   
SELECT  * from TempResult
```

Now I want when Count =1 then Record will search on basis of @search variable otherwise not, Canany one help me on this but remember i want any conditional statement within the CTE not out side means no repetition of CTE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are after:

```
WITH TempResult AS
(
 SELECT * FROM Temp WHERE (@Count<>1 OR Title LIKE '%'+@Search+'%')
)
SELECT * FROM TempResult
```

**Explanation:**

The records will be filtered with `Title LIKE '%'+@Search+'%'` **only** when @Count != 1.

To be more precise:

When `@Count` = 1, it will go for the second part of `WHERE` clause.

When `@Count` !=1, it will not go for the second part since `WHERE` clause returns `true` already.

Comment: But I also want to search when Count =0, only diffrence is when Count =0 then where clause not work then show all record

Comment: @user3136255: It will do the trick even when Count=0. Please let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: @user3136255: Its a pleasure, my friend.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like

```
WITH TempResult as          
    (              
        Select * from Temp WHERE @count <> 1 OR Title = @Search
    )   
SELECT  * from TempResult
```

Comment: But I also want to search when Count =0, only diffrence is when Count =0 then where clause not work then show all record

Comment: @user3136255 Wrong sign, it should be `WHERE @count <> 1`. Try it now.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
WITH TempResult as
(
 SELECT * FROM Temp WHERE @Count=1 AND Title LIKE '%'+@Search+'%'
  UNION ALL
 SELECT * FROM Temp WHERE @Count<> 1
)
SELECT * FROM TempResult
```

Comment: +1 : Over larger data-sets this `UNION` pattern *may* be significantly better that a single query due to how execution plans are pre-compiled to suit 'all possible cases' *(each half being better tailored to available indexes, etc)*.  It should, however, be `UNION ALL` to avoid redundant de-duplication of data.

Comment: Yes it should be `UNION ALL` as there is no duplicate data. Updated answer. Thanks @MatBailie for inout.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
WITH TempResult as
(
     SELECT * FROM Temp WHERE (@Count=0) OR (@Count <> 0 AND Title LIKE '%'+@Search+'%')
)
SELECT * FROM TempResult
```

Comment: Why the down vote? I'm sure this would do what you want